# Array index in kotlin

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, generics, indexing

Let's say i have an array that contains the names of the fruit and i want to take it out if write the first letter. I confuse because i don't what the keyword when i got this kind of question.

```
fun main() {
var char = readline()
val name = arrayOf("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Dragonfruit")
}
```

When i type "a", the result is apple and so on.

I can't use

Thank you for helping me.
I just learn about kotlin.

Comment: you want all the words starting with letter "a" or just the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val char = readLine()
    val name = arrayOf("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Dragonfruit")

    val filteredNames = name
         .filter { word -> word.startsWith(char.orEmpty(), ignoreCase = true) }
    System.out.println(filteredNames)
}
```

Given your description, it seems to me that we should not be case-sensitive while checking and hence the `ignoreCase = true` as a parameter in `startsWith()` method.

Comment: Thanks! it works very usefull for me.

Comment: Is your issue solved now? If it is and my answer helped you consider upvoting it and even accepting it as the answer so that it can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array based on the input character:

```
fun main() {
    val char = readLine()
    val names = arrayOf("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Dragonfruit")

    val filteredNames = names.filter { 
         it.startsWith(char.orEmpty(), true) 
    }
}
```

For clarification:

- `it` refers to the current element being iterated.
- The function `startsWith()` receives a string used for comparison as the first parameter, and a boolean indicating if the evaluation should ignorecase or not.
- since `readline()` is an optional string (`String?`) type, `char` can be null (when you run the application, you can always choose to press the *Enter* key without typing in anything). To avoid a NullPointerException being thrown upon comparison inside `startsWith()`, you use the method `.orEmpty()`, which is a nicer way to write `it.startsWith(char ?: "", true)`.

If instead of all elements starting with a character, you only want the first one, you can call `first()` on the array:

```
fun main() {
    val char = readLine()
    val names = arrayOf(
        "Apple", 
        "Albatroz", 
        "Anaconda", 
        "Banana", 
        "Cherry", 
        "Dragonfruit"
    )

    val firstElementStartingWithChar = names
        .first { 
             it.startsWith(char.orEmpty(), true) 
        }
}
```

If you choose to type the letter *a* as an input, `firstElementStartingWithChar`  will only contain "Apple".

Comment: thank you! for give me a lesson, it very usefull for me